# How to create a 'read-only' schema field in Tridion 2013?

Tags: 2013, cme

How to make a Text-box field as read-only in component editing screen. This field would be populated by custom URL functionality.

Comment: Check out this link from Robert Curlette: http://yabolka.com/gui-extension-readonly-and-hidden-fields-in-tridion-2011-and-up/

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty sure if there is anything special in SDL Tridion 2013 for this, however you can use GUI extension to achieve the same.

You may want to follow this blog link of Albert - http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/

Please note this post is for SDL Tridion 2011 but I hope it would not introduce much conflict and at least give you some pointer.